# FB Comments never stops loading

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, xfbml

This is the fb comments code snippet from [facebook comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)  The problem is it shows the comments, but never finishes to load.

I use java/spring/jsp (no wicket).

I tried : http://example.com & my_external_website_url & some_internal_url
All have same issue. It got to be something basic I believe. But did any one else face this issue?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<myappid>";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<my_url>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I also tried the XFBML version with same result. Any pointers will help. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "loading"?  Do you perhaps mean constant network activity?  Ajax calls non-stop coming in and out of the component? If the comments are being displayed... what exactly constitutes "still loading"?

Comment: The "loading graphic" isn't going away. It  gives the perception that the comments plugin isn't done loading yet (although that is not the case & I see the comments)

Comment: Any chance you can post a public URL so we can take a look?

Comment: Have you set the correct Facebook namespace in your opening `<html>` element? `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
`

Comment: Wish I could, unfortunately not an option here..

Comment: Yes I tried adding the namespace. Same result.

Comment: Does the comments plugin on the demo page Facebook has do the same thing, or is it only on your web page that this occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to happen only when trying to access the comments plugin from a webapp running on localhost server. My local url had a port number 8080. (like myhostfiledlocalurl:8080/..).

I moved the webapp to QA (still within intranet environment) & the "foreever loading" issue went away. QA url used the default port 80. But I got a warning message saying the qa url is unreachable (which is expected as it is not visible to public).

Then I moved the webapp to a public facing site & everything started working like expected.

**UPDATE:** 
I changed local to run on port 80. Forever-loading problem does not happen anymore.